# Lotus Notes Agent: java.io.IOException: Access is denied

Tags: javaagents

I have a java agent that will list all the files from Google Drive using the api provided from google developer (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java).

However, the agent is having a "Access is denied" error when trying to create the "tokens" folder from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\framework" directory.

I have created the "tokens" folder manually but the error still occured.

I have put all the required jar files in "/jvm/lib/ext" and updated the java policy on my local as follows:

// custom java security policy, to allow external jar file access
grant { permission java.util.PropertyPermission "http.keepAlive", "read, write"; };
grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; }

My actual agent code

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Drive API Java Quickstart";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

public void NotesMain() {

  try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

      this.main();
      // (Your code goes here)

  } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

```
/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
 * @return An authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
 */
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = JavaAgent.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}

public static void main() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    FileList result = service.files().list()
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
            .execute();
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the error Ive'd got from the java debug console.

java.io.IOException: Access is denied.
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:894)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory$FileDataStore.(FileDataStoreFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(FileDataStoreFactory.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.AbstractDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(AbstractDataStoreFactory.java:55)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(StoredCredential.java:171)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:744)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:209)
    at JavaAgent.getCredentials(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.main(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)